# loading an image to The DOM and then append it to a div element, I get an error Uncaught TypeError: imagecontainer.appendchild is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html document, as seen below that I want to take an image as input and display it back the class div with the classname **imagecontainer**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label for="profile">Please insert your image</label>
        <input type="file" name="profile" id="profile">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>

      <div class="imagecontainer">
        
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript file that I am using can be seen below

```
const button = document.querySelector('button')



button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    const imagecontainer = document.getElementsByClassName('imagecontainer')

    const cardImageInput = document.getElementById('profile')
    const myImage = cardImageInput.value
    cardImageInput.value = ''


    const image = document.createElement('img')
    image.src = myImage
    image.classList.add('profile-image')

    imagecontainer.appendchild(image)
    console.log(imagecontainer)


   
})
```

The code seems simple enough but I cant figure out the problem, everytime it runs I see this error message on the web console `Uncaught TypeError: imagecontainer.appendchild is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>`

---

---

---

---

---

---

solved the problem by changing `getElementByClassName` and instead used `querySelector` ...However after running the program I got an error **c:\fakepath\FdkmPsOWQAINAt8.png:1 GET c:\fakepath\FdkmPsOWQAINAt8.png net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME** I was told this was a security implementation of the browser.

The work around I have found for this is by using the **FileReader**
editing my javascript here is the code that worked for me

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const fileInput = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    const imagecontainer = document.querySelector('.imagecontainer');
    const image = document.createElement('img');

    var fReader = new FileReader();
    fReader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);

    fReader.onloadend = function(event){
        
        image.src = event.target.result;
        image.classList.add('profile-image');
         }
    
    imagecontainer.appendChild(image);
    console.log(imagecontainer);
   
});
```

Comment: I have changed it to **appendChild** but still get the same error, is it possible for you to replicate it to see what I am seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues in your code:

1. The correct method name is `appendChild`, not `appendchild`. As JavaScript is case-sensitive, the correct code should be `imagecontainer.appendChild(image)`.
2. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements. You need to access the specific element from the collection before you can use the `appendChild` method on it. You can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead, which selects the first matching element.

**Code Example:**

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

    const imagecontainer = document.querySelector('.imagecontainer');

    const cardImageInput = document.getElementById('profile');
    const myImage = cardImageInput.value;
    cardImageInput.value = '';


    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = myImage;
    image.classList.add('profile-image');

    imagecontainer.appendChild(image);
    console.log(imagecontainer);
   
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="profile">Please insert your image</label>
  <input type="file" name="profile" id="profile">
</div>
<div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</div>

<div class="imagecontainer">

</div>
```

Comment: the code works finally, another related question is why doesnt an image show after selecting it, It shows **c:\fakepath\FdkmPsOWQAINAt8.png:1          GET c:\fakepath\FdkmPsOWQAINAt8.png net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME** again thanks

Comment: @deniskiplangat, The error message, `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`, is due to the fact that browsers do not allow direct access to the local file system for security reasons. The file path starting with *C:\fakepath\* is a security measure implemented by the browser to prevent websites from accessing the user's local file system

Comment: so how do websites input profile image of users, how do they do it...what I am trying to create would be just frontend and no access to the server...how do they do it